# ggplot - what is the unit of stat_density2d plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

stat_density2d is really a nice display for dense scatter plots, however I could not find any explanation on what the density actually means. I have a plot with densities ranging from 0 to 400. What is the unit of this scale ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

The density values will depend on the range of x and y in your dataset.

`stat_density2d(...)` uses `kde2d(...)` in the `MASS` package to calculate the 2-dimensional kernal density estimate, based on bivariate normal distributions. The density at a point is scaled so that the integral of density over all x and y = 1. So if you data is highly localized, or if the range for x and y is small, you can get large numbers for density.

You can see this in the following simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(50,0,5),rnorm(50,20,5)),
                  y=c(rnorm(50,0,5),rnorm(50,20,5)))
ggplot(df1, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()+ 
  stat_density2d(geom="path",aes(color=..level..))
```

[image]

```
set.seed(1)
df2 <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(50,0,5),rnorm(50,20,5))/100,
                  y=c(rnorm(50,0,5),rnorm(50,20,5))/100)
ggplot(df2, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()+ 
  stat_density2d(geom="path",aes(color=..level..))
```

[image]

These two data frames are identical except that in `df2` the scale is 1/100 that in `df1` (in each direction), and therefore the density levels are 10,000 times greater in the the plot of `df2`.